# Laravel eloquent delete

Tags: laravel, model, controller, eloquent

I am looking for some assistance on how to understand Laravel Eloquent model.

I need to delete `User` by `Id`, and I have tables `Main_info`, `Personal_info`, `Holidays`, `other_info`, `fm_day`, `oth_daysoff`.

On the tables, I have inserted `UserId` field, so I need to delete selected `UserId` from all of the tables? May someone help me on how I can do this with Laravel Eloquent model?

Here is my view with `delete` submit button and post method:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">

    <div class="col">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-head-man">
                <span>Filter type: </span>&nbsp;
                <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm">Position</a>&nbsp;
                <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm">Active/No</a>&nbsp;
                <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm">Employment type</a>
                <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm">Location</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-12">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header">
                <h3 class="card-title">List of employees</h3>
            </div>

            <div class="table-responsive">
                <table class="table card-table table-vcenter text-nowrap">
                    <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th class="w-1"><a href="#" class="sort-act">ID<span class="caret"></span></a></th>
                        <th><a href="#" class="sort-act">First Name<span class="caret"></span></a></th>
                        <th>Last Name</th>
                        <th>Position</th>
                        <th>Active/no</th>
                        <th>Employment type</th>
                        <th>Location</th>
                        <th></th>
                        <th></th>
                    </tr>
                    </thead>

                    <tbody>
                    @foreach($allData as $data)


                        <tr>
                        <td><span class="text-muted">{{ $data->id }}</span></td>
                        <td>{{ $data->first_name }}</td>
                        <td>
                            {{ $data->last_name }}
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            {{ $data->position }}
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            {{ $data->employment_type }}
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <span class="status-icon bg-success"></span> Active
                            <span class="status-icon bg-danger"></span> No
                        </td>
                        <td>{{ $data->location }}</td>

                        <td class="text-right">
                            <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm">Manage</a>
                            <div class="dropdown">
                                <form action="/deleteFromHome" method="post">
                                    {{csrf_field()}}
                                    <input style="display: none;" type="text" name="deleteUserId" class="form-control" id="inputName3" value="{{ $data->id }}">
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm">Delete</button>
                                </form>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <a class="icon" href="javascript:void(0)">
                                <i class="fe fe-edit"></i>
                            </a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    @endforeach
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>

</div>
```

Here is how my controller doing it now:

```
public function deleteUserFromHome(Request $req)
{
    $userId = $req->input('deleteUserId');

    OtherInfo::where('id', $userId)->delete();
    OthDaysInfo::where('id', $userId)->delete();
    HolidaysInfo::where('id', $userId)->delete();
    FMdaysInfo::where('id', $userId)->delete();
    PersonalInfo::where('id', $userId)->delete();
    PersonalInfo::where('id', $userId)->delete();
    MainInfo::where('id', $userId)->delete();

    return redirect('home');
}
```

Maybe there is some better way to delete all data from all tables about selected userId?
I need some example how I can make Laravel Eloquent model to delete with function HasMany or some else?

Comment: If you have setup pivot tables then you can simply pass the user model and use detach() method. https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#updating-many-to-many-relationships

Answer (score 1):

You can use `->onDelete('cascade')`when you create your table migrations. 
For instance,

```
// consider a sample migration below for a table with a foreign key on your users table
Schema::create('main_info', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->integer('user_id');
    $table->foreign('user_id')
          ->references('id')
          ->on('users')
          ->onDelete('cascade');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

And then you can easily just delete the specified user, and Laravel will take care of deleting it's child records.

```
$user = User::find($id);
$user->delete(); // this will also delete any record for this user on main_info table
```

[Read more here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/migrations#foreign-key-constraints)

Comment: Still getting this error: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1451 Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`emtn_internal`.`other_info`, CONSTRAINT `other_info_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`id`) REFERENCES `main_info` (`id`)) (SQL: delete from `main_info` where `id` = 90)

Comment: can you show your code on which that error persist? From the error itself, it says, it's from the `other_info` table with a foreign key `id` that references to your `main_info` table. So, it's not from the connection between your `users` table and `main_info` table. If you can provide your table structures (`users` and `main_info`, `other_info`)  then that will make easier for people here to help you.